# Unix domain sockets and select

Tags: c, sockets

Just to make sure sure, one can call select on a Unix Domain socket. Correct? Also one can mix different types of sockets in a select statement. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  The only type of file descriptor you should not put in a `select` call is a regular file, because regular files are *always* considered ready, even if reading from them would block.

Answer (score 1):

of course,a socket/pipe/unix domain/msgqueue and something like that will be ok~

you may use sockpair right now , select / poll / epoll can get it.